# Can Regular Expressions that contain repeating patterns be reduced with shorthand or other techniques?

Tags: javascript, regex

**Background)** The Regular Expression pattern below appears long but most of it consists of a repeating pattern.

This range is used 3 times,

```
[a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}<>_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\]
```

```js
var repeatingPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}<>_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\](( [a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}<>_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\])|([a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}<>_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\]))/
```

The English translation of this Regular Expression is:

1. The first character must be in the range.
2. The second character must be a space followed by a character in the range.
3. OR the second character must be a character in the range.

**Question)** I write that range so many times is there a way to do that with shorthand or some other technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript `RegExp` does not support [regex subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html), so you cannot - in JavaScript regex - define a pattern and refer to the same *pattern* from within the same regex.

Why not use the `RegExp` constructor and strings?

In ES6:

```
const pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!\'|?(),~[{}<>_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\]';
const regex = new RegExp(`^${pattern}((${pattern})|(${pattern})`);
```

(I'm assuming that I matched the pattern correctly in the constructor! I might have missed a character here or there.)

Comment: Using the constructor is brilliant and I didn't think of it.  I checked it should probably work in IE.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 2):

You could use your range and add a non capturing group with a space and your range and repeat that group 2 times with a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) `{2}`

You might use boundaries `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the string.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\](?: [a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\]){2}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WRKIoy/1/)

```js
var repeatingPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}<>_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\](?: [a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}<>_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\]){2}$/;
var strings = [
  'a { #',
  'a { # %',
  '#'
];
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + repeatingPattern.test(s));
});
```

**Edit**

If you want to capture 2 characters where the second character could be preceded with an optional whitespace you could use a whitespace followed by a questionmark `?`.

If you want to capturing the second character including the optional whitespace you could capture it in a group `()`.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\]( ?[a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\])$`
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/83hsV6/1)

```js
var repeatingPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}<>_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\]( ?[a-zA-Z0-9&+".;!'|?(),~[{}<>_:`*#\/\-\^\]\\])$/;
var strings = [
  'a #',
  'a { #',
  'a { # %',
  '#'
];
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + repeatingPattern.test(s));
});
```

Comment: That's very interesting.  `?:`  But why is a non-capturing group needed?  I thought that was a way to exclude portions of a pattern.

Comment: A non capturing group does not exclude portions of a pattern but does not  keep the match as a group where you can refer to. I have added an update to my answer if you exaclty want to match 2 characters where the whitespace before the second character there is optiona. My inital answer is based on a total of 3 characters instead of 2 where there is a whitespace between each character.